App crashing when task switches to another app and goes to background when a task is ongoing
I have a view that is set to disappear after 5 seconds and it's working okay normally aside from this scenario:

user does the action that makes the view show
user immediately switch to another app and stays there for a few seconds
user switches back to my app
app is unresponsive

There are no errors in console aside from these
-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = dismissAutoFillPanel, customInfoType = UIUserInteractionRemoteInputOperations

Snapshotting a view (0x109264080, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

Here's what my code looks like:
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = AppState()

    @Published var notificationArray: [NotificationItem] = []

    func addNotification(_ notification: NotificationItem) {
        notificationBoxArray.append(notification)
    }
    
    func removeNotification(_ notification: NotificationItem) {
        self.notificationBoxArray.removeAll { $0.id == notification.id }
    }

}

struct NotificationBoxModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    mainNotificationBoxView()

                }.animation(.spring(), value: AppState.shared.notificationBoxArray)
            )
        .enableInjection()
    }

    #if DEBUG
    @ObserveInjection var forceRedraw
    #endif

    @ViewBuilder func mainNotificationBoxView() -> some View {
        if AppState.shared.notificationArray.count > 0 {
            VStack {
                ForEach(AppState.shared.notificationArray){ notification in
                    NotificationBoxView(notificationText: notification.message, notificationType: notification.type) {}
                        .padding(.bottom,16)
                        .task {
                            do {
                                try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
                                await MainActor.run {
                                    AppState.shared.removeNotification(notification)
                                }
                            } catch {
                                logger.error("Task.sleep error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        }
    }
}

Previously the task happens in the addNotification box and the issue is still present
func addNotification(_ notification: NotificationItem) {
    notificationBoxArray.append(notification)
    Task {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
            await MainActor.run {
            AppState.shared.removeNotification(notification)
            }
        } catch {
            logger.error("Task.sleep error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

I also tried commenting out the task and the deletion of the notification and the freeze is gone so the problem is really in the .task

Try doing it on a detached task Task.detached { // stuff }  and see if the freezing still happens. Alternatively use a timer instead of sleep()

tried what you suggested but it still didn't work

@mev – The traditional advice to move to a background thread and or use a Timer only applies when using legacy/blocking renditions of sleep. But Swift concurrency’s Task.sleep is a safe, non-blocking pattern. The problem rests elsewhere.
